# Rewrite query using cursor (perhaps with a join) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, inner-join, sql-insert

I have a query (not written myself) and I am trying to make it run faster. I have seem this [SQL Query with Cursor optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990020/sql-query-with-cursor-optimization)

Cannot see if the answer applies for my case. Is it possible to rewrite this query?

The structure is:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TableA

declare @myvar as varchar(255)


declare cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
for SELECT SUB_TRANS
    FROM TableB
open cur

fetch next from cur 
into @myvar

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT many_thing
    from 4_tables_with_join(Note: @myvar is included as a join condition)



    fetch next from cur 
    into @myvar

END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: It is hard to provide a useful answer from this pseudo-code only (I am refering to the `from` clause of the `insert` statement). You would probably need to build a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @GMB thanks. the variable from the cursor is used in a join condition. I am more looking for a general hint in the form of pseudo-code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a "general hint": you most likely don't need the cursor logic at all. I would recommend rewriting this as a straight `insert ... select` query.

As pseudo-code, this would look like:

```
insert into tablea (col1, col2, ...)
select many_thing
from tableb tb
inner join ... -- use "tb.subtrans" here in the join conditions instead of "@myvar"
```

Comment: Thanks, I am waiting for the result to see if they are the same. But it is not extremely faster...Still taking a lot of time

Comment: @David Performance issues are often best attacked by starting with the _actual execution plan_. You may want to post a new question with DDL for your tables, the query and the execution plan. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your future questions.

Comment: @HABO Yes I am looking at Execution plans I will get back. But right now everything is slow and it is weekend.. Is there a DMV i can use to get a feel for what is going on?

Comment: @HABO Also testing is so slow. what strategy should I use when I want to test these queries. I cannot wait 1 hour every time I want to get the actual execution plan. Or is this my only option? May create som test tables so the job is smaller?

Comment: @HABO: Well now I have the execution plan but I don't think I can share it here. But from statistics IO I have this for a workfile: Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 5546722, physical reads 6, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: @David You're not likely to solve a performance problem through a string of comments on someone's answer to a different question. "Oh yeah, `Worktable`. Did you index the 7th and 3rd columns in one index with the 3rd column `desc`?" isn't the kind of answer we can come up with from "I saw the execution plan and you can't." If you can provide the execution plan then post a new question with all of the supporting data, e.g. DDL and query. Otherwise, start searching for articles about updating index statistics, identifying "missing" indexes, finding bottlenecks, ... .